# Editing a message that has already been edited in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, edit

I have a Discord bot coded in Python, and I have a setup command for it where it creates different colour roles in the server. Instead of it sending a message every time it creates a role (which would fill up the chat), I want it to edit the current message every time it's created a role. Here's the broken code I have so far:

```py
@client.command()
async def setup(ctx):
  guild = ctx.guild
  message = await ctx.reply("**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[..........] 0% complete - Creating colour roles: Red`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Red", colour=discord.Colour(0xe94d4d))
  message2 = await message.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[/.........] 16.6666667% complete - Creating colour roles: Orange`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Orange", colour=discord.Colour(0xce7816))
  message3 = await message2.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[///.......] 33.3333334% complete - Creating colour roles: Yellow`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Yellow", colour=discord.Colour(0xceb716))
  message4 = await message3.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[/////.....] 50.0000001% complete - Creating colour roles: Green`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Green", colour=discord.Colour(0x4ace16))
  message5 = await message4.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[///////...] 66.6666668% complete - Creating colour roles: Blue`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Blue", colour=discord.Colour(0x1674ce))
  message6 = await message5.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[/////////.] 83.3333335% complete - Creating colour roles: Purple`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Purple", colour=discord.Colour(0xb316ce))
  await message6.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[//////////] 100% complete!`")
```

Is there a way to make it edit an already edited message? I tried the above and it returned the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'
```

Comment: Have you tried just using the same `message` object? I don't think `.edit` returns anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the first comment on my question, it worked!
The code is:

```py
@client.command()
async def setup(ctx):
  guild = ctx.guild
  message = await ctx.reply("**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[..........] 0% complete - Creating colour roles: Red`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Red", colour=discord.Colour(0xe94d4d))
  await message.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[/.........] 16.6666667% complete - Creating colour roles: Orange`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Orange", colour=discord.Colour(0xce7816))
  await message.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[///.......] 33.3333334% complete - Creating colour roles: Yellow`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Yellow", colour=discord.Colour(0xceb716))
  await message.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[/////.....] 50.0000001% complete - Creating colour roles: Green`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Green", colour=discord.Colour(0x4ace16))
  await message.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[///////...] 66.6666668% complete - Creating colour roles: Blue`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Blue", colour=discord.Colour(0x1674ce))
  await message.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[/////////.] 83.3333335% complete - Creating colour roles: Purple`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Purple", colour=discord.Colour(0xb316ce))
  await message.edit(content="**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[//////////] 100% complete!`")
```

Instead of creating a new message object every time, you just use the same message object.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing the message, you can delete it and write the new one. You can do something like this:

```py
@client.command()
async def setup(ctx):
  guild = ctx.guild
  message = await ctx.reply("**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[..........] 0% complete - Creating colour roles: Red`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Red", colour=discord.Colour(0xe94d4d))
  await client.delete_message(message)
  message = await ctx.reply("**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[/.........] 16.6666667% complete - Creating colour roles: Orange`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Orange", colour=discord.Colour(0xce7816))
  await client.delete_message(message)
  message = await ctx.reply("**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[///.......] 33.3333334% complete - Creating colour roles: Yellow`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Yellow", colour=discord.Colour(0xceb716))
  await client.delete_message(message)
  message = await ctx.reply("**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[/////.....] 50.0000001% complete - Creating colour roles: Green`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Green", colour=discord.Colour(0x4ace16))
  await client.delete_message(message)
  message = await ctx.reply("**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[///////...] 66.6666668% complete - Creating colour roles: Blue`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Blue", colour=discord.Colour(0x1674ce))
  await client.delete_message(message)
  message = await ctx.reply("**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[/////////.] 83.3333335% complete - Creating colour roles: Purple`")
  await guild.create_role(name="Purple", colour=discord.Colour(0xb316ce))
  await client.delete_message(message)
  message = await ctx.reply("**Sonata is currently setting up!**\n"
  "`[//////////] 100% complete!`")
```